# How to wrap Swagger responses?

Tags: swagger

I need wrap all responses accordingly to our API specification:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        <response>
    }
}
```

Can Swagger also wrap all responses like this?

At this time I'm creating new responses for all models and etc., but this is very painful :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# WebApi, you can use [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to directly integrate Swagger into your code and then generate the Swagger spec (2.0) more easily.